# Flashes Translation / Sylius Locale

Tags: symfony, translation, sylius

I created locale in sylius backoffice as en_GB for the english version (different with en_US if I had to use it); in flashes messages we only see in SyliusCoreBundle flashes.en.yml configuration. I guess there is no difference between english language and american one, however there is a big one.

First, I tried this:

- define en_GB locale in backoffice
- configure locale and locale_fallback in symfony according to en_GB language
- define a flashes.en_GB.yml into app/Resources/translations as explained here http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/flash.html

Translation did not work using this method.

Then, I tried to require sylius/locale component from packagist according to my current symfony version (update sylius language component):

- I tried to require the version v0.19.0 using command line  composer *require sylius/locale:v0.19.0*
- Composer always try to use the monolog ^3.0 version (even if I try to change the monolog version in composer.json)

Therefore, currently, I cannot override/use flashes configuration as explained in documentation, using the defined locale in sylius backoffice, and I cannot require the sylius/language component according to my current sylius/Symfony version (current used sylius version: "sylius/sylius": "^1.0@dev").

Do you know any fix to deal with flashes message translation ?

Thanks,

JMO.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the locale in the channel you are using?

BTW current Sylius version is beta-1, not 0.19.

Comment: Hello CoderMaggie, yes I did. Actually, I use a v0.19 sylius version because of some dependencies.